# length of a log line with logback

Tags: logback

I looked on the web but i did not find the answer to my question.
I use **logback 1.1.3 with slf4j 1.7.10** and in my log file, log line are break with a new line like this : 
date level  thread Caller+1  at  "class name, line name" \n - msg

I would like to have the same output but without the \n, has anyone an idea ?

Here is my appender :

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/logs/log.log</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %caller{1..2} - %msg%n
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please format your question using standards set forth in Help.

Comment: In particular please review http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve